# angular2 accessing and assigning object properties returned by service to component local variable

Tags: angular, typescript

My video service:

```
public getExercise(exerciseId): Observable<Exercise[]>{

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

        return this.http.get(this.base_url + exerciseId + '/', options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In my template I have:

```
<!-- Show current level -->
<div align="center">
 <h6>Ihre aktuelle Intensitätsstufe ist {{intensity_level}}</h6>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showVideo" align="center" class="video-container">
        <iframe [src]="exercise_video_url | safe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And my component:

```
export class VideoPage implements OnInit {

    exercise: Exercise[];
    errorMessage: string;

    public exercise_id: number;
    public intensity_level: number;
    public rating: number;
    public exercise_video_url: string;
    public current_date: string;


    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public videoService: VideoService) {

        console.log(this.navParams.get('exerciseId'));
        this.exercise_video_url='';

        this.exercise_id=this.navParams.get('exerciseId');

    }

    ngOnInit(){

        this.getExercise()
    }

    getExercise(){

        this.videoService.getExercise(this.exercise_id)
        .subscribe(
            exercise => {
                this.exercise = exercise;
                console.log(this.exercise[0].video_url)

            },
            error => {
                this.errorMessage = <any>error;
            });

        this.exercise_video_url=this.exercise[0].video_url;

    }   
}
```

However, the object properties are not being assigned to my local variables so that I can bind them on template. My service simply returns one object that's why I used `this.exercise[0]` and if I try to write the same line outside get(), it gives compilation error (which seems obvious). What should be done here?

The console line prints the url.

Comment: update the code of  **VideoService** to know what your service does!

Comment: updated with video service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are assigning the video url outside of the `subscribe` function.

```
getExercise(){

    this.videoService.getExercise(this.exercise_id)
    .subscribe(
        exercise => {
            this.exercise = exercise;
            console.log(this.exercise[0].video_url)
            // NEW LINE
            this.exercise_video_url=this.exercise[0].video_url;
        },
        error => {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        });

    // OLD LINE
    // this.exercise_video_url=this.exercise[0].video_url;

}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I have one question here: outside the subscribe function it should be available right? Or it doesn't wait and simply executes the the below code (i.e. inside subscribe it is guaranteed to execute only when value is available)?

Comment: It's async it will run and then will come back to the `subscribe` function, it's like a callback the subscribe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped

Answer (score 0):

You are not mapping your response content to your required **Exercise** model, 
Modify your service as below

```
public getExercise(exerciseId): Observable<Exercise[]>{

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

        return this.http.get(this.base_url + exerciseId + '/', options)
        .map((response: Response) => <Exercise[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```